# How to make chrome compatible with Jupyter for Anaconda?

Tags: python, google-chrome, anaconda

I am an anaconda user and Jupyter is a neat tool to run python code. However, for my macbook, I can't open it in Chrome (This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.),but it works in Safari, I have tried to reinstall chrome, but I still can't fix it. My system is Mac OS 10.11.5.
Who knows how I can fix it? 
I can understand that the problem might be not specific enough, but I have been puzzled by this problem for quite a period of time.

Comment: What version of Jupyter are you running?

Comment: My Jupyter version is 4.3.1

Comment: Have you checked the network settings on Safari and Chrome, are they the same?

Comment: Can you list the exact steps you use? And what port number.

Comment: Can you please specify the message displayed after executing $ jupyter notebook

Comment: @PrakharAgarwal the message I can see is This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: @Shay I just set the chrome as the default browser and type `jupyter notebook` in terminal, the port is 8889? I can see this number in the url.

Comment: @asettouf What do you mean network setting, say where I can find it in Chrome?

Comment: For instance, the proxy settings of the browser: http://www.googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-advanced-settings/Google-chrome-proxy-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem in the git page for Jupyter:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438

Try going to directly to http://localhost:8888/tree
or whatever port you are using.

Comment: I have tried, it didn't work either, the same response. "This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Answer (score 0):

Download jupyter notebook from link below 
[Download jupyter notebook](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html)

Once you downloaded it, run it any browser it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste the link with token from the terminal to chrome.

It should work after that.

The steps are :

1. Cd to directory u want to go to
2. Type jupyter notebook , a browser window opens up after this command.
3. If safari opens up copy paste the link from safari to chrome.
4. It might ask u for a token the first time. That can found in the terminal where jupyter command is typed.